# Error exporting data into Excel file using R tool

Tags: r

I imported .csv file to excel using excel in first task.

Now i imported .csv into R  and exported R data into Excel file using command 
write.table(aviation,"D:\00Projects\R\Data\ aviation.xls",sep="\t")

The problem i am facing is 
This is .csv converted to Excel using Excel

```
Event Id     Investigation Type      Accident Number     Event Date         
20130710X74631   Accident    WPR13LA321               07/10/2013        
20130709X10955   Accident    WPR13LA317               07/08/2013
```

This is .csv converted to Excel using R tool. Data has been shifted by one column. Not getting why is it ?

```
Event.Id    Investigation.Type  Accident.Number Event.Date  
1            20130710X74631      Accident    WPR13LA321      07/10/2013 
2            20130709X10955      Accident    WPR13LA317      07/08/2013
```

Why EventID column data has been shifted and replaced with 1 and 2 numbers.

Comment: See help(write.table). By default rownames also are exported (numbers 1 and 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `?write.table`, try this:

```
write.table(aviation,"D:\00Projects\R\Data\ aviation.xls",sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: `..., row.names = FALSE )` is the safer choice, although just `F` will work as long as you don't assign `F` a different value.

Comment: @vaettchen agree, I'm just used to typing `F`. Yes, better be safe.